# 'NoneType' TypeError when trying to append variable containing .write() to a file

Tags: python, wxpython

I am attempting to save what I've written to a file in a variable and then append it to a wx.ListCtrl widget. However I get a 'NoneType' TypeError each time I try.

```
with open("birthday.txt", 'a') as database:
     name = database.write(name_data + '\n')
     mail = database.write(mail_data + '\n')

     if int(month_data) < 10 and int(day_data) < 10:
        date = database.write('0' + day_data + '/0' + month_data + '/' + year_data + '\n')

     elif int(month_data) >= 10 and int(day_data) >= 10:
        date = database.write(day_data + '/' + month_data + '/' + year_data + '\n')

     elif int(month_data) < 10 and int(day_data) >= 10:
        date = database.write(day_data + '/0' + month_data + '/' + year_data + '\n')

     elif int(month_data) >= 10 and int(day_data) < 10:
        date = database.write('0' + day_data + '/' + month_data + '/' + year_data + '\n')
        database.write('\n')

index = self.list.InsertItem(sys.maxint, '1')
self.list.SetItem(index, 1, name)  # Error message occurs here
self.list.SetItem(index, 2, mail)
self.list.SetItem(index, 3, date)
```

The error message:

```
TypeError: ListCtrl.SetItem(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'long'
  overload 2: argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Comment: It would help if you could include the whole error message, so that we would know what line of code caused it.

Comment: I will update the post. But the problem occurs when appending the variables to the wx.ListCtrl widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to a file does not return the thing you wrote there in python. Here is your problem:

```
 name = database.write(name_data + '\n')
 mail = database.write(mail_data + '\n')
 ...
 date = database.write('0' + day_data + '/0' + month_data + '/' + year_data + '\n')
```

These write-operations do not return anything, so name, mail and date will always be `None`. That is why you get the error. Just remove the assignment:

```
database.write(name_data + '\n')
```

Instead you can just use the original variables in the `SetItem`-call, assuming you have defined them somewhere.

```
index = self.list.InsertItem(sys.maxint, '1')
```

By the way why would you pass this `sys.maxint` instead of, say, 0? I do not know much about wxpython. I'll make a guess and assume that with that the function returns list length as the index and will insert to the end, whereas 0 would insert to the start. Well, unimportant here probably.

Anyway, you can set the original data to the items:

```
self.list.SetItem(index, 1, name_data) 
self.list.SetItem(index, 2, mail_data)
self.list.SetItem(index, 3, date_data)
```

Ok you do not actually have the `data_data` like that, but that is another matter, I suggest you to look up how to use [the datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to parse date data from strings. Or you can just do it the same way you did with the file write. Or at least a bit better would be to save the data to a variable there:

```
 data_data = '0' + day_data + '/0' + month_data + '/' + year_data + '\n'
 database.write(date_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)